# pyqt5 demo launcher: does it exists ? Where to find it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I begin to use pyQT5 with python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04.
I installed the package `pyqt5-examples` that provides a lot of examples that can be run individually.

Does somebody know where I could find a global demo launcher from which I could access to all the demo items ? Such a thing exists for wxWidgets and it is really helpful.

A README file says:

```
The source code for the launcher can be found in the examples/demos/qtdemo
directory in the PyQt package.
```

I don't find this directory on my installation.

Comment: The [file-list for the pyqt5-examples package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/pyqt5-examples/filelist) shows that the launcher is installed as `/usr/share/doc/pyqt5-examples/examples/qtdemo/qtdemo.py`.

Comment: I got it ! Many thanks.